# Tomcat doesn't start with YAWL engine

Tags: tomcat, yawl

I am new to Yawl. I have successfully installed the Yawl and is able to start YAWL engine and YAWL editor. But when I try to access the JSP (`http://localhost:8080/resourceService/faces/Login.jsp`), the only error I can see is Unable To Connect. localhost:8080 is not showing the tomcat home page as well. The login button is also disabled in Yawl Control Panel.

It seems that tomcat service is not started by default with the Yawl engine.

Comment: Stop it, clean it and restart it.. ? did you try that?

Comment: While trying to stop. the control panel stuck and does nothing then. IS this the problem of the version of jdk used? I am using jdk 7

Comment: Can any one have any idea about that. It is urgent for me

Answer (score 0):

**Solution1**

Try downloading the latest version of the control panel jar from:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/yawl/files/updatecache/engine/controlpan...

Replace the one in /controlpanel and see if that goes any better.

**Solution2**

I found a way to start the Engine.

1)First i try to start the "startup.bat" and i get this on my screen:
"The JRE_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly. This environment variable is needed to run this program."

2)I add this lines in the startup.bat (YAWL-3.0\engine\apache-tomcat-7.0.55\bin , open it with Notepad and change the XXX text part with your path ):

```
SET JRE_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre
SET CATALINA_HOME=C:\Users\xxx\Documents\YAWL-3.0\engine\apache-tomcat-7.0.55
SET TCPORT=8080
```

SET CHECKPORTRESULT_FILE=C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Temp\chckprtrslt
    "%JRE_HOME%\bin\java.exe" -cp "%MISC_PATH%" CheckPort %TCPORT% > "%CHECKPORTRESULT_FILE%"
   SET /p TC_LISTEN= < "%CHECKPORTRESULT_FILE%"
    DEL "%CHECKPORTRESULT_FILE%"

3) Now start the YAWL 3.0 Control Panel an click on "Start" (its still staying "Engine is Starting" in yellow
4) If you start now the "Startup.bat"

Reference: http://www.yaug.org/content/tomcat-doesnt-start-yawl-engine